# Formula not calculating if prior value 0

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with two columns. One that tallies defect counts per week on a different row per week and one that calculates the % change in bugs from one week to the next.  When the prior weeks value is 0, the % change displays as 0% (because we're calculating a % based on 0 which = 0).  I'm unsure how to handle this.

The % Change formula calculates as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(C6),,((C6 - C5)/C5)),0)
```

Again, this works great so long as C5 doesn't = 0. When it does, the % change is 0% which is not correct.

Comment: if C5 is 0 the IF returns an error which the IFERROR turns to 0. What is the expected result?

Comment: Thinking through this a bit more, I believe I am thinking about it incorrectly.  0 is 0 so a % change from 0 would make sense. It can't be a number as it's not...it's 0.  Unless it's .00001 or something else. I think I'm good here, thank you though!